# woocommerce - coupon on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce for Wordpress to build a webshop.

I have removed the coupon from cart and added it to the checkout. When I enter the coupon code and hit 'apply coupon', it completes the whole form and goes directly to the payment gateways. I want to make sure the coupon first gets added to the order total. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce already provides provision to add coupon from the checkout page you don't need add. Probably you have edited the checkout page template and added the coupon form inside the checkout form that's why checkout form is submited on clicking apply coupon. In order to customize the coupon in checkout page you have to look into wooocmmerce checkout.js.

Comment: added may not be the right word. I merely moved it. I placed the action '<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit' ); ?>' somewhere else in the template(in review-order.php).

Comment: Aha, I see it. I've put the coupon in review-order, which is in the checkout <form> just like you said. Can I wrap the coupon in its own form?

Comment: What is wrong with the coupon already provided by wooocommerce